# Does endianness refer to ordering within a defined array or memory or also the actual memory used?

Tags: memory, endianness

I'm having trouble expressing my question in words, but I think I can express it visually quite simply. Storing the string `abcd`, is the difference between Big and Little Endian this:

```
memory address  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | ...
little endian   | d | c | b | a |
big endian      | a | b | c | d |
```

Or this:

```
memory address  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | ...
little endian   | d | c | b | a |
big endian                  | a | b | c | d |
```

My attempt in words: does "endianness" refer to the ordering of bytes within a specific memory "array", where in both cases the array begins at the same point in memory, or does it refer to both the ordering and the actual array used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Endianness refers to the ordering of bytes used to store a single multi-byte numerical value. The "big endian" system in your second image is storing 4-byte integers unaligned, which no system would normally do.